# Как лучше хранить файлы (изображения, видео) на сервере сайта?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, файлы, веб-сервер, файловая-система

Интересует вопрос, как на сегодняшний момент лучше хранить файлы на сервере?
Знаю, что есть 2 основных способа хранения - напрямую в БД (что на выходе не очень производительно) и хранение файлов на сервере, а в БД хранить путь до файла. В связи с этим вопрос:
1) как все таки оптимально хранить файлы?
2) если предполагается, что файлов будет очень много, как их правильно хранить? (отдельный сервер или прямо там же, где и сам сайт или же выгоднее будет положиться на облачный сервис хранения)
3) если на сайте понадобятся изображения разных размеров (допустим уменьшенная версия аватара пользователя), то как лучше это изображение хранить? (при загрузке пользователем изображения сохранять изображение и кучу его обрезанных версий для разных случаев или же хранить одно обрезанное до определенного размера изображение, а в нужных местах, где нужна "версия поменьше" сжимать его средствами CSS? Насколько затратны эти способы?)
4) касательно способа хранения "файлы - на сервере/пути - в БД" - что делать при случае, когда каким-нибудь образом запись в БД с путем до файла пропадет, а файл на сервере останется (и наоборот, файл пропадет, а запись в бд будет)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) как все таки оптимально хранить файлы?

Если файлы небольшого размера и их количество невелико, то можно и в БД. Плюсы: бэкап всегда сохраняет файлы и бд, можно применять каскадные операции. Минусы: БД становится большого размера. Бэкап и восстановление могут длиться часами

> если предполагается, что файлов будет очень много, как их правильно хранить?

Зависит от типа и частоты операций, которые вы будете с ними проделывать. Если большую часть операций составляет чтение, то можно и на cdn или отдельном сервере. Опять же можно начать с хранения в директории на том же сервере, при увеличении размера примонтировать в эту директорию отдельный диск, по мере роста можно воспользоваться сетевыми хранилищами с доступом по iSCSI, NFS и т.д.

Если файлов много, следует учитывать, что файловые системы имеют ограничение на количество файлов в одном каталоге. Поэтому стоит продумать структуру подкаталогов.

> 3) если на сайте понадобятся изображения разных размеров

Если позволяет место, то лучше оставлять оригинал. Тогда, при смене дизайна оффлайн-скриптом на сервере вы сможете перегенерировать нужные вам размеры, или "переналожить" водяной знак с новым дизайном. 
Некоторые используют "ленивый" ресайз. Постоянно хранятся оригиналы, нужные размеры генерируются при первом доступе к сущности и сохраняются во временный каталог, далее используются уже измененные файлы. При отсутствии активности измененные размеры чистятся по крону

> что делать при случае, когда каким-нибудь образом запись в БД с путем до файла пропадет, а файл на сервере останется

тут уж ничего особо не сделаешь. Только устраивать периодическую синхронизацию, с перебором файлов и проверкой наличия записи в БД